# Authentication Flow Issue: 'invalid_client' Error in ID.me to AWS Cognito Integration

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito

Hello StackOverflow Community,

I'm working on integrating ID.me with AWS Cognito for user authentication in our application. The process involves several steps, and while the initial redirection to ID.me works correctly, we're encountering an issue in the subsequent authentication phase.

Here's a breakdown of our process and the problem:

Redirection to ID.me: This step works as expected. Users are successfully redirected to ID.me for authentication.

User Authentication at ID.me: This is where we face the issue. Despite ensuring that the client ID is correctly entered (we've checked it multiple times), we receive an error indicating 'Client authentication failed due to unknown client, no client authentication included, or unsupported authentication information; error=invalid_client'.

Return to AWS Cognito: Post-authentication, when users are redirected back to our AWS Cognito, the error is included in the token body.

Final Redirection to AWS app: This step also works correctly, but it's affected by the earlier error.

We've followed the ID.me and AWS Cognito documentation closely but can't seem to resolve this 'invalid_client' error. Has anyone experienced a similar problem or can offer insights into what might be going wrong? Any advice or troubleshooting tips for this specific part of the authentication flow would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your help!

We followed the documentation